# How do you represent a plane wave propagating at an angle $\theta$ w.r.t. $z$-axis?

Tags: optics, waves, vectors, fourier-transform

There is a plane wave $\exp(i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}-i\omega t)$, where $\mathbf{k}$ is the wave vector. Suppose this wave propagates at an angle $\theta$ w.r.t. $z$-axis. What will be the wave vector components along $x$, $y$ and $z$-axis?
My doubt is that $x$, $y$, $z$ axis have units of meters where $\mathbf{k}$ has units of 1/meter. So, I am a bit confused as to how I can represent the components along $x$, $y$ and $z$-axis?

Can someone please explain?

A useful link (Fig 34-11):
https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_34.html

Answer (score 2):

> There is a plane wave $\exp(i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}-i\omega t)$, where $\mathbf{k}$ is the wave vector. Suppose this wave propagates at an angle $\theta$ w.r.t. $z$-axis. What will be the wave vector components along $x$, $y$ and $z$-axis?

Specifying only the angle $\theta$ with respect to the z-axis does not completely specify the direction.

You also need to specify the azimuthal angle $\phi$.

But anyways, assuming this is what you mean, the vector $\vec k$ is in the direction of propagation, so the vector $\vec k$ you desire is:
$$
\vec k = |k|\left(
\hat x \sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)
+\hat y \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)
+\hat z \cos(\theta)
\right)
$$
$$
\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\left(
\hat x \sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)
+\hat y \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)
+\hat z \cos(\theta)
\right)\;,
$$
where $\lambda$ is the wavelength.

> My doubt is that $x$, $y$, $z$ axis have units of meters where $\mathbf{k}$ has units of 1/meter. So, I am a bit confused as to how I can represent the components along $x$, $y$ and $z$-axis?

Both $\vec k$ and $|k|$ have units of inverse length, whereas all the unit vectors and all the trig functions are unitless.

Comment: thankyou. However, in the figure given in the link Feynman lectures (Fig. 34-11), wavelength is represented in the coordinate system, which has dimensions of meters.